# Errors crawling content sources with SharePoint 2010

Tags: search, crawling

We currently have a SharePoint 2010 Single server farm. The patch level is SP1 with June CU. The issue is with incremental or full crawls of content sources. The error is as follows:

```
The system cannot find the path specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070003)
```

The paths that are used http://intranet and http://mysites.  If I were to reset the index and do a full crawl we would have success with no error as stated above. The problem is always on subsequent crawls.

We also confirmed the permissions of the gthrsvc_Osearch14 is set appropriately for the search acct.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your Index location is Corrupt.

Do you have a test environment where a similar behavior is occuring? If so I would recommend a backup of your SP server then do a hard delete of the Index files (Gather n stuff). Then do an Index reset and start a full crawl once again.

Any other SharePoint Logs being written during this error?

Comment: I am not seeing any other logs written. Just the error I attached through the crawl logs.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried crawling a port number instead of a name? That usually does the trick for me

Answer (score 0):

This [hotfix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/949516) resolves the following error message:

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: The system cannot find the path specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070003)